# pip install SciPy creates an error for installation

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, scipy

Hi I am constantly having this error below. I am a novice using code and been facing this issue which I cannot resolve. Can someone help?

Collecting scipy (from -r requirements.txt (line 49))
Obtaining dependency information for scipy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/15/e73734f9170b66c6a84a0bd7e03586e87e77404e2eb8e34749fc49fa43f7/scipy-1.11.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached scipy-1.11.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
Obtaining dependency information for scipy from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/b8/947f40706ee2e316fd1a191688f690c4c2b351c2d043fe9deb9b7940e36e/scipy-1.11.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
Using cached scipy-1.11.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (59 kB)
Using cached scipy-1.10.1-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
Using cached scipy-1.10.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (42.2 MB)
Using cached scipy-1.9.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (39.9 MB)
Using cached scipy-1.9.2-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (39.9 MB)
Using cached scipy-1.9.1.tar.gz (42.0 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [55 lines of output]
The Meson build system
Version: 0.62.2
Source dir: C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f
Build dir: C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f.mesonpy-di88mzar\build
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.9.1
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

```
  ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running "icl " gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다"
  Running "cl /?" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다"
  Running "cc --version" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다"
  Running "gcc --version" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습 니다"
  Running "clang --version" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없 습니다"
  Running "clang-cl /?" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니 다"
  Running "pgcc --version" gave "[WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다"

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f\.mesonpy-di88mzar\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  + meson setup --native-file=C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311 C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ecec4diw\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f\.mesonpy-di88mzar\build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 969, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      with _project(config_settings) as project:
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 948, in _project
      with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
      return next(self.gen)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 777, in with_temp_working_dir
      yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 682, in __init__
      self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 713, in _configure
      self._meson(
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 696, in _meson
      return self._proc('meson', *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_4nk1alw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\mesonpy\__init__.py", line 691, in _proc
      subprocess.check_call(list(args))
    File "C:\Users\corea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=C:\\Users\\corea\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ecec4diw\\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f\\.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=C:\\Users\\corea\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311', 'C:\\Users\\corea\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ecec4diw\\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f', 'C:\\Users\\corea\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ecec4diw\\scipy_3c6340d51124457a8297a77c748f217f\\.mesonpy-di88mzar\\build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I have tried anaconda to install SciPy as well since I kept facing an issue. Yet it didnt resolve my problem.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit Python interpreter? There are 64 bit wheels available, so pip should've installed one of those if it could. I'm guessing you have a 32 bit interpreter, and there aren't any pre-built wheels available for 32 bit.

Comment: @AndrewNelson Hi I am a beginner in python as well as this site and enthusiastic to learn about it. I didn't realize that the small comment section was here so I couldn't reach to you. The book instruct me to download two version of Python - 64 bits with path and 32 bits without path which I did. Then I can connect with 64 bits from python and 32 bits in -venv environment. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Don't bother with 32 bit interpreters, they're obsolete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Install a C/C++ Compiler**: The error logs indicate that the system couldn't find any C/C++ compiler. If you're on Windows, you can download and install Microsoft's C++ Build Tools from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).
2. **Update `pip` and `setuptools`**: Outdated versions of these can sometimes cause issues. Open your command prompt (cmd) and run:

   ```bash
   pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
   ```
3. **Try Installing SciPy Again**: Once the C/C++ compiler and pip are set up, try installing SciPy again:

   ```bash
   pip install scipy
   ```
4. **Anaconda Option**: Since you've tried Anaconda already, make sure you're creating a new environment and then installing SciPy in that environment:

   ```bash
   conda create -n myenv python=3.11
   conda activate myenv
   conda install scipy
   ```